# How to handle JSON with XStream in Java?

Tags: java, xstream, google-custom-search

I have created a Google custom search engine and initiated the query using the HTTP GET. Now Google is returning the result as JSON format. I was just wondering how to format this JSON output into a Human readable way.

For example:

```
Title: The matrix
htmlTitle: "The matrix.."
```

I have seen XStream is recommended in many forums. But not sure how can I get this to work.

Can someone please help me with this.

Just for reference, I am giving the HTTP GET code in here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyBp_5Upf6h0QSXR8UveLs4_c6lAmGW_7B8&cx=014783642332862910131:opc1zgsvfhi&q=matrix&alt=json");
    System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
    System.out.println(responseBody);
```

Comment: I don't know if it's exactly the same  that you want to do, but google provides a Java library. May be it's simple to use it: http://code.google.com/intl/ca/apis/gdata/client-java.html

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a Class that maps the Goolge response, then use a code like this (from the [XStream tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html)):

```
String json = "{\"product\":{\"name\":\"Banana\",\"id\":\"123\""
        + ",\"price\":\"23.0\"}}";

XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.alias("product", Product.class);
Product product = (Product)xstream.fromXML(json);
System.out.println(product.getName());
```